# How to encode byte array directly to mp3 in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, mp3, arrays, shinemp3encoder

I successfully managed to record sound in my AIR app and packaged to iOS and Android. I used as3wavsound and bytearray.micrecorder. For the mp3 encoding i used shinemp3Encoder. This uses my wave bytearray and then transforms it to mp3. It takes too long (iPad1 - 20 sec recording - 49 sec encoding to mp3) and i was wondering if i could encode the original bytearray directly to mp3 or is there a faster method to do the encoding?

Comment: In a word: Nope. MP3 encoding is a time consuming process, it will always take a noticeable amount of time. If you're using Alchemy version of Shine encoder, it's as fast as it's gonna get. You could possibly improve the situation by encoding the stream in parallel to recording, but that would require a rewrite of the encoder.

Answer (score 0):

Sure - porting anything Alchemy to Native Extension(for iOS/ANdroid) will help with the speed. I've been porting AS3 GIF Encoder to FlasCC(former Alchemy) - speedup was about 3.5x. After porting to native extension speedup was about 10x. Currenntly working on various ports of encoders, might add this one to the list :)

Comment: that would be sweet. i'm looking forward to that ANE.